# Why Next 13 App Reloaded when route changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-router

I am working on Next 13 Application where when ever i click on navigation links from sidebar it changes the route but my application get reloaded. Instead directly component should be replace as it is SAP should not reload.

Using **APP ROUTE**

Defining Route

```
 export const dashboardRoute: ItemRoute = {
  key: 'dashboard',
  title: 'Dashboard',
  path: '/',
};
```

And creating Links like below in **SideBar** Component

```
<Link
  id="item-child"
  href={child.path}
  >
   {child.title}
 </Link>
```

Then I have **layout.tsx** where i am wrapping this application with some recoil and brandings looks like below

```
<html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <title>App Title</title>
      </Head>
      <body>
        <ErrorBoundary
          fallback={
            <GlobalError
              error={undefined}
              reset={function (): void {
                throw 'Function not implemented.';
              }}
            />
          }
        >
          <RecoilRoot>
            <ConfigProvider
            >
              <Branding>
                <StyledJsxRegistry>
                  {!['/login', '/forgot-password'].some(
                    (element) => pathName.includes(element)
                  ) ? (
                    <LayoutTypeOne>{children}</LayoutTypeOne>
                  ) : (
                    <LayoutTypeTwo>{children}</LayoutTypeTwo>
                  )}
                </StyledJsxRegistry>
              </Branding>
            </ConfigProvider>
          </RecoilRoot>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And then i have **page.tsx** where i am rendering my some component which needed in dashboard screen and also i am checking if user is logged in if not then i am redirecting it to the Login Page

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `material-ui`, there is a chance that you have imported `Link` from material-ui instead of importing from `next/link`. Please check the import line.

Comment: I am using ant design